# CMake, Microsoft Visual Studio, and Monolithic Runtimes

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

I'm building a file using the CMake Build System and Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler. When I have CMake generate the visual studio project, the project contains the commandline to build a "Multi Threaded DLL" type of runtime -- one which depends on msvcrt.dll. For various reasons I'm not going into right now, I cannot depend on msvcrt.

Is there a way to tell CMake to modify this option in it's construction process?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use the following piece of code to link to the static CRT:

```
if(MSVC)
# We statically link to reduce dependencies
foreach(flag_var CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO)
    if(${flag_var} MATCHES "/MD")
        string(REGEX REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" ${flag_var} "${${flag_var}}")
    endif(${flag_var} MATCHES "/MD")
    if(${flag_var} MATCHES "/MDd")
        string(REGEX REPLACE "/MDd" "/MTd" ${flag_var} "${${flag_var}}")
    endif(${flag_var} MATCHES "/MDd")
endforeach(flag_var)
endif(MSVC)
```

Comment: This is overkill isn't it? Wouldn't "foreach() string(replace, /md, /mt) endforeach()" work just as well? (i.e. get rid of the if() and the /MDd). The first replace will match the second one anyway, and there is no point searching for a match before you just do the replacement.

Comment: Works for me, inside the foreach(flag_var...): 
`string(REGEX REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" ${flag_var} "${${flag_var}}")`

Comment: The options for doing this are documented under "How can I build my MSVC application with a static runtime" at http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees

Comment: More correct link to official documentation how to build with MSVC with static link to CRT:
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_build_my_MSVC_application_with_a_static_runtime.3F

Comment: I had some trouble implementing this. No matter where I had put this, the resulting projects ended up still using /MD or /MDd. I eventually realized that the /MD or /MT flag was never being set at all, and it was defaulting to /MD. Adding an else ... string(CONCAT ...) part to the code fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I replace the dynamic flags (/MD and /MDd) with static flags (/MT and /MTd). Also, I found that I needed to cache the flag variables in order for it to stick.

```
if(MSVC)
    foreach(flag_var CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO) 
        string(REGEX REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" ${flag_var} "${${flag_var}}")
        string(REGEX REPLACE "/MDd" "/MTd" ${flag_var} "${${flag_var}}")
    endforeach(flag_var)
    SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG}" CACHE STRING "MSVC C Debug MT flags " FORCE)    
    SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}" CACHE STRING "MSVC CXX Debug MT flags " FORCE)
    SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE}" CACHE STRING "MSVC C Release MT flags " FORCE)
    SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}" CACHE STRING "MSVC CXX Release MT flags " FORCE)
    SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL}" CACHE STRING "MSVC C Debug MT flags " FORCE)    
    SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL}" CACHE STRING "MSVC C Release MT flags " FORCE)
    SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}" CACHE STRING "MSVC CXX Debug MT flags " FORCE)    
    SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}" CACHE STRING "MSVC CXX Release MT flags " FORCE)
endif()
```